# How to split makefile into separate modules

Tags: scripting, makefile, include, gnu-make, modularity

I have a large makefile used to control a large engineering flow. 
Before the first target, I have many variables, conditional branches and functions definitions to set up the environment and control some options.
Even inside targets, I may have some parts from different logical roots.

Let's say I have something like this:

```
var1 := val1
var2 ?= val2
...

# fn1 defintion
...

if conditions ...
...
...

target1: depends
    ....
    ....

.....
```

.

My question is:
Is it possible to split the makefile into different parts at any position (i.e inside or outside targets) - Like if all included parts are "concatenated" together in a single file this file will be exactly the same as my makefile?

Something like this:

make1.mk:

```
var1 := val1
var2 ?= val2
...
```

make2.mk:

```
# fn1 defintion
...
```

make3.mk:

```
if conditions ...
...
...
```

make4.mk:

```
target1: depends
    ....
```

make5.mk:

```
....
....
```

makefile:

include make1 make2 make3 make4 make5 ...

Thank you!

Comment: Updated:
I was able to include variables assignment into separate file using:
    -include fileName

However, I can not include additional target contents!

Comment: Included makefiles are included at the point of the `include` directive exactly and targets in included makefiles work just fine. Can you show an https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve of this not working?

Answer (score 1):

As @Etan Reisner commented, [GNU make's `include` directive](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Include.html) operates conceptually similar to a compiler pre-processor, reading each `include`d makefile and processing their content inline at the point where they were `include`d, as if you had generated the main makefile from a template that `cat`s each `include`d file in place. (Unlike a pre-processor, where this *actually* happens, the pre-processor outputting intermediate files containing source file modifications, `make` just processes each `include`d file inline *in memory* when it encounters them.)

So, you almost had it right in your OG psudocode, but need to `include` actual filenames:

```
include make1.mk make2.mk make3.mk make4.mk make5.mk
```

Better to leverage `make`'s support of shell globbing:

```
include *.mk
```

..making sure to name the files in appropriate alphanumeric order per your shell's globbing rules so the glob expansion will result in `make` inserting file content in the desired sequence.

Make will also interpolate variables in the `include`d _filename_s. Imagine the following possible use case for this - imagine that in addition to having a bunch of common makefile content you want to always include, your make system also has different operating "modes" or target categories, each requiring a different set of `include`d files.

Let's say your make system supports some operations in your `local` dev environment and some in a `remote` cloud environment in AWS EKS. In this case you could do something like this:

```
include common.mk $(MAKE_MODE).mk
```

Like any `make` variable, `MAKE_MODE` could be specified at the command line:

```
make myapp MAKE_MODE=local
```

or maybe it makes sense for `MAKE_MODE` to be determined automatically, say based on which target(s) were invoked:

```
EFFECTIVE_MAKECMDGOALS=$(or $(MAKECMDGOALS), $(.DEFAULT_GOAL))

LOCAL_TARGETS=docker-build-push docker-run docker-shell
REMOTE_TARGETS=eks-run eks-shell

ifneq ($(filter $(LOCAL_TARGETS),$(EFFECTIVE_MAKECMDGOALS)),$())
MAKE_MODE=local
else
ifneq ($(filter $(REMOTE_TARGETS),$(EFFECTIVE_MAKECMDGOALS)),$())
MAKE_MODE=remote
endif
endif

include common.mk $(MAKE_MODE).mk
```

Another, more common, use-case for conditional `make` `include`s is to "flatten" `make` operations in large, hierarchical projects to avoid the pitfalls of recursive `make`, where a top-level `make` invokes `make` in project subdirectories.